# How to use SASS in REACT SSR?

Tags: reactjs, sass, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to create a simple React application using SSR, but I encounter a problem when importing a sass file into my component, I get *SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'*. 
I use the following scripts to bundle and run my app:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore dist/",
  "dev-bundle": "webpack -w -d"
}
```

I use the following loaders to translate sass into js:

```
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "style-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
              }, // compiles Sass to CSS
            }
          ]
```

I am not sure why this syntax error occurs, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please paste the complete  error stack trace? Because i am assuming this is related to something else.